# wpf game 3d object from 3d studio

Tags: wpf, object, 3d, directx

I have a wpf application and I like to add 3d objects.
The objects are created in 3d studio max.
The application is a game. So the question is connected with game programming.
How objects from 3d studio are used in the game (that supports direct x) ?
Is there any standard format to export the object to and use in in the wpf app ?

Regards

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/3d-meshes-for-wpf-xaml

Answer (score 0):

This Xaml-Exporter might also help: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2009/03/31/daily-tip-how-to-import-3d-model-to-wpf-from-3d-max.aspx